# How to get different value from radio button?

Tags: javascript

I want the rate to change when I select different currency. But right now it only show my initial checked value. Here my code

```js
   let btn = document.querySelector("button");
    let priceDisplay = document.querySelector("#price");
    let currency = document.querySelector('input[name=rate]:checked').value;
    
    btn.addEventListener("click",function(){
      let XHR = new XMLHttpRequest();
      XHR.onreadystatechange = function(){
        if(XHR.readyState == 4 && XHR.status==200){
           let data = JSON.parse(XHR.responseText);
           let price = data.bpi[currency].rate;
          priceDisplay.innerText = price + " " + currency;
        }
      }
      XHR.open("GET","https://api.coindesk.com/v1/bpi/currentprice.json");
      XHR.send();
    })
```

```html
  <h1>Bitcoin Current Price is: <span id="price"></span></h1>
    <p>Pick your currency: </p>
    <input type="radio" id="USD" name="rate" value="USD" checked>
    <label for="USD">USD</label><br>
    <input type="radio" id="GBP" name="rate" value="GBP">
    <label for="GBP">GBP</label><br>
    <input type="radio" id="EUR" name="rate" value="EUR">
    <label for="EUR">EUR</label><br>
    <button>Refresh Data</button>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to put the querySelector() code

```
btn.addEventListener("click",function() {
    let currency = document.querySelector('input[name=rate]:checked').value;
    ....
}
```

inside the click event handler. The reason is because it's executed only once before the click event triggered, so it got only 1 first checked value. When you click the button, it needs new updated value.